# How to link.so into a Visual Studio ndk dynamic shared library

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I want to use [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) api in my ndk dynamic shared library.
I try to add libtess.so and liblept.so in

```
Project->Properties->Linker->Input->Library Dependencies
```

and add this lines:

```
[path]\libtess.so
[path]\liblept.so
```

But in this case i can't use tesseract includes.
I also try to compile tess-two and it's dependencies using some visual studio dynamic shared library projects (tess, lebpt, jpeg, png) but it can't compile jpeg and png libraries and gives several errors!

So main question is can i link a/some .so file(s) into a Visual Studio ndk dynamic shared library without having any source code of those .so files?

Comment: Header files exist separately from dynamic link library files. You need to set up include path so compiler will be aware of header locations.